# Merge GWT generated files

Tags: javascript, gwt, merge, gwt2, bootstrapping

I'm trying to create a JavaScript library from GWT.
The big deal: I want to merge the JavaScript files into one.

Basicly GWT generate two files: 
[Your_Project].nocache.js   => The bootstrap 
[MD5].cache.html            => The proper(?) JavaScript API.

index.html---**load**--->[Your_Project].nocache.js ----**load**---->[MD5].cache.html 
I'm trying to change that by:
index.html  ---**load**--->everything.js

But how to merge [Your_Project].nocache.js and [MD5].cache.html into one JavaScript file...?

I'm not sure it gonna be an easy task.

Martin Magakian

Comment: Are you sure GWT is what you want to be using here? The reason I ask that you're trying to subvert the bootstrap process, which is actually a major feature of GWT. GWT is a tool for building web applications, not JS libraries.

Comment: A late reply, the idea was to compile in one JavaScript file in order to load the JavaScript on an iPhone. In this case I knew the webbrowser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but only for one single distinct compilation. For example, the following compiles one single file for Firefox:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko"/> 
<add-linker name="sso"/>
```

Because GWT generates browser specific versions, this means only one browser is supported in the compiled file. If you need other browsers change the `user.agent` and compile again. Note if you do want to support multiple browsers, you need to serve the correct version to the user, something GWT does for you if you use the normal compilation process. So I'm not sure if this is what you really want.

Comment: +1 Using the single script linker is generally only a good idea if you only plan on supporting one browser (and locale).

Comment: "only a good idea if you only plan on supporting one browser" - ... or if you can use "soft permutations" (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<collapse-all-properties />
<add-linker name="sso" />
```

in your `ProjectName.gwt.xml` file. This way all permutations are joined in a single JavaScript file.

Comment: Even better, it is possible to inline the entire single js file into the host page to further reduce http requests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678675/deploy-gwt-application-as-single-javascript-file