# Deploy GWT Application as Single JavaScript File

Tags: gwt

The compiled JavaScript output of a GWT application is divided into various files, for instance

- *.cache.html
- *.gwt.rpc
- hosted.html
- *.nocache.js

...

I know this is done with the purpose of minimizing the size of the JavaScript, which has to be downloaded by users. For instance so that a Firefox user does not have to load the JavaScript specifically compiled for IE6.

However, especially for small GWT applications it might often be faster to download a single file of say 500kb rather than make two sequential requests first for the 5kb *.nocache.js script and then for the rest of the app (cache.html files, etc.).

This leads me to the question: **Is there any framework or procedure to bundle the output of the GWT compiler into a single JavaScript file**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can merge all permutations in a single file by using so-called ["soft permutations"](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations).

Then, you can inline your *.nocache.js into the HTML host page (e.g. using a JSP's `@include` directive) to cut one additional request (you might have to add a `<meta name=gwt:property content='baseUrl=myapp'>` where `myapp` is the subfolder where the *.nocache.* files are located).
AFAIK that's what Google are doing for their GWT apps.

Alternatively, you can run the *permutation selection* on the server-side if you can totally replace the selection script (*.nocache.js) with server-side content negotiation (based on User-Agent and Accept-Language request headers for instance) that can directly generates a `<script>` tag for the appropriate *.cache.js file (provided you use the `xsiframe` linker).

AFAIK, Google use all these techniques for their GWT apps (such as Google Groups). For a small app, though, I'm not sure it's worth the effort…
Also, the last two techniques work best when your HTML host page is already dynamic and therefore already non-cacheable; otherwise you're mostly moving the problem, not solving it.

I wonder whether the `sso` linker can be used when you collapse all properties and soft-permutations down to a single hard permutation.

Comment: Thanks! Soft Permutations were the piece missing for me. The GWT compiler is really amazingly flexible!

Comment: The sso linker now supports soft-permutations [changeset 10938](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10938)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's maybe not something you want. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453716/66416 to this stackoverflow question: [Merge GWT generated files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4453302/66416).

Comment: Thanks! Compiling permutations for individual browsers and then joining them together manually also looks like a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to accomplish this: Writing a custom Linker for GWT. Two examples for linkers which compile into a single JavaScript file are:

- [GwtNodeLinker.java](https://github.com/cretz/gwt-node/blob/master/src/org/gwtnode/dev/linker/GwtNodeLinker.java) from Gwt Node project
- [ServerSingleScriptLinker.java](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js/blob/master/htmlparser/gwt2/src/com/envjs/gwt/linker/ServerSingleScriptLinker.java) from Env.js project